# Using same button to enter different text in textfield

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, thread-sleep

I'm working on a project to insert numbers based on the number of button clicks using a counter. There's only one single button involved. When that button is pressed once, it should enter 1 in the text field. If that button is pressed again within 3 seconds, 1 should be replaced with 2. If it is pressed after 3 seconds, then the next digit should be entered in the same fashion. I've added my code below.

I'm having some trouble with this program. When i press the button twice within 3 seconds, it enters "12" in the JTextField. Also I'm having trouble to reset the counter after one digit is entered.Hope you understand my question.

```
  package timertry;


  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
  import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
  import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class TimerTry extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public JFrame panel1;
JTextField tf;
JButton button;
int counter=0;

public TimerTry() {
    panel1=new JFrame("Single button keypad try");
    panel1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 

    tf=new JTextField();
    tf.setEnabled(false);
    tf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);



    button=new JButton();
}
 public void launchFrame(){
    panel1.setLayout(null);
    panel1.setVisible(true);
    panel1.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

     panel1.add(tf);
    tf.setSize(300, 50);
    tf.setLocation(500, 150);
    tf.setEnabled(false);
    tf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);







    panel1.add(button);
    button.setSize(360,50);
    button.setLocation(900, 250);
    button.setLabel("Press");
    button.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    button.addActionListener(this);



 }





public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    TimerTry tt=new TimerTry();
    tt.launchFrame();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Thread thread=new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{

                sleep(3000);
                counter++;
                if(counter==1){
                    tf.setText(tf.getText()+counter);
                }
                else if(counter==2){
                    tf.setText(tf.getText()+counter);
                }
                else if(counter==3){
                   tf.setText(tf.getText()+counter);
                }
                else {
                   tf.setText(tf.getText()+counter);
                }


            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Don't wrap your logic within a Thread, each time your press a button, you are starting a completely new and independent thread

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
if(counter==1){
    tf.setText(tf.getText()+counter);
}
else if(counter==2){
    tf.setText(tf.getText()+counter);
}
else if(counter==3){
   tf.setText(tf.getText()+counter);
}
else {
   tf.setText(tf.getText()+counter);
}
```

Just add `tf.setText("");` before each `tf.setText(tf.getText() + counter);`

Or even better, change your `try-catch` for this one.

```
try{
    sleep(3000);
    counter++;
    tf.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
}
catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

instead of getting text from `tf` just set text, it will replace the text it had, instead of adding it again.

Your program does:

**1 clic**

`tf` = 1

then you get in an imaginary `String` let's call it `textOfTF`

`textOfTF` = 1

**2 clic**

`textOfTF` = 1 (because you get it from `tf.getText()`) 2

So

`textOfTF` = 12

And so on.

And as a recommendation don't use `thread.sleep()` on swing applications, I would recomend using [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

`thread.sleep()` will make your application to freeze, while a swing timer don't.

Comment: That is going to mask the problem. The real problem is in OP's approach.

Comment: yep just noticed he was getting text from textfield and adding it to the counter. See edit @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your current approach....

1. You are spawning a new, independent, `Thread` each time the button is clicked. Each `Thread` waits for 3 seconds and the increments the counter regardless
2. `tf.getText()+counter` is actually converting the `counter` to String before it concatenates the result.  This means if the text is "1" and the counter is "2", the value will be converted to "12", not "3". Instead, you should just convert the counter to a `String` directly

There are a number of ways you might resolve this problem...

1. You could check the current time against the last time the button was clicked, if the value is less then 3 seconds, you can increment the counter, otherwise you would need to reset and start again.
2. You could use a Swing `Timer`, which is set to a non-repeating delay of 3 seconds. When the button is clicked, you would restart this timer and increment the `counter`. When the timer is finally triggered, you would reset the `counter` to 0

Answer (score 0):

If i did understood you correctly this should be the answer you are looking for. Please comment if something is wrong ! So assume we run the program for 6 seconds , which is divided into 2 period these are 0 -> 3 -> 6 , if you keep pressing the button between 0 and 3 the jtextfield  changes to single number display but after 3 seconds another 3 seconds starts actually so there is no before and after within your logic , they cancel each other , so if you don't press the button until 6 seconds 1 and 2 will be displayed. You are able to press 3secondsbutton as  much as you can for each 3 seconds which will only change the display mode to the single value. Actually the display mode is changes from multiple numbers to single number or vice versa for each 3 seconds which depends on button pressed or not. If you want to change multiple number display start from the last value , I mean not from beginning you need keep the last value and start displaying from that point so you might need to make some modification on  below code.

[image]

**Your Fields Should be like this**

```
    int count=0;
    String currenttext = "";
    boolean key;
    int seconds = 0;
```

**Start Button Action**

```
    private void startbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        timer();
        threesecondsbutton.setEnabled(true);

    }
```

**Timer Calling Method**

```
 public void timer(){

   timer.setInitialDelay(3000);
   timer.start();

 }
```

**Overide Timer**

```
  private Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    // Single Display 
    if(key==true)
    {

       count++;
       currenttext = currenttext + Integer.toString(count);
       jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(count));

    } 

    // Multi Display   
    else
    {
        count++;
        currenttext = currenttext + Integer.toString(count);
        jTextField1.setText(currenttext);


    }

    seconds = seconds + 3; 
    jLabel3.setText(Integer.toString(seconds));

    key = false ;


}
});
```

**3 Seconds Button This Button Sets the key  to check the button is pressed within 3 seconds or after 3 seconds**

```
 private void threesecondsbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       count++;
       currenttext = currenttext + Integer.toString(count);
       jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(count));
       key = true;

}
```